# Wrong display of count(*) result with PgAdmin and postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm a little confused with my data, postgres returns wrong value with a simple count(*)

I use a :

```
select count(*) from DimUsers
```

it returns : 74280

this one :

```
select count(*) from DimUsers group by user_type
```

Returns :
72134,12288, 89850

this one :

```
select * from DimUser
```

displays a table of 1674280 rows

And my full database is estimated by pgadmin to 1674280 rows.

I can't see what is wrong with it, this happened to anyone before?

Comment: You should include what version of the PostgreSQL you are using.

Comment: I think something is lopping off some leading digits...  16**74280** ends with the digits 74280.

Comment: it's postgesql 9.3, but this weird lopping off, i've never noticed before !

Comment: the 1st table ends with s DimUsers while the second two are DimUser is it just a typo ? Not quite sure where from you know 1674280 rows.

Comment: @cur4so sorry typo, pgadmin returns a 1674280 rows table from a select *

Comment: I'd say 1674280 rows is a bit too much for a display,I assume this is a stat you got from pgadmin and pgadmin is not postgresql as such. Are the first two also from pgadmin? Can you get to your db with a psql terminal ? Are the results differ ?

Comment: pgadmin can display 1674280 row but right you're right about the lopping it's the pgadmin that is lopping off the 2 last leading digits ! I just cheked with psql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar problem.  However I found that pgAdmin 3 was in fact returning the correct count value, except the column size for the count column was not auto-sized correctly to fit the data and thus it seemed like it was only returning the last 5 digits of the count.  Increasing the size of the count column by using the column resize on the header row allows you to see the full number, but unfortunately you have to do this for every query you run.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by rachekalmir the issue is pgAdmin 3.  You can overcome this by giving "count" a longer column name. then you will see the full number.

```
select count(*) as mybiggggcount from DimUsers
```